# Print a Matrix using for loop - Python

Tags: python

I'm new in Python. I'm facing some problem to code in Python. My problem is-

> I tried in many ways to print a Matrix as it is initially looks like. Suppose we have a matrix. Basically we have a 2D list given below:

```
  matrix = [
    [1, 2, 3],
    [4, 5, 6],
    [7, 8, 9]
 ]
```

Now if I do a code like the snippet given below:

```
for row in matrix:
   for col in row:
      print("col")
```

then output will be-

```
1
2
3
.
.
.
```

Again if we do code like the snippet given below:

```
for row in matrix:
    for col in row:
        print(col, end=" ")
```

Then output will be-

```
1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9
```

But I want output as the matrix is previously looks like:

```
1 2 3
4 5 6
7 8 9
```

Please help me to get rid of this problem.

Comment: How is the matrix stored? String, file...?

Comment: After the second loop of your second attempt, try adding `print()`

Answer (score 2):

You were close, all you have to do is print a new line right after each `col`, so-

```py
for row in matrix:
    for col in row:
        print(col, end=" ")
    print()    # Prints an empty string, which will be accompanied by a new line
```

Comment: Just `print()` will do.

Answer (score 1):

Add an empty print statement after the inner loop:

```
for row in matrix:
    for col in row:
        print(col, end=" ")
    print()
```

Answer (score 0):

Just add an extra `print` statement after the inner loop to change the line and it is note `python` specific you have to do this in all the language.

```
for row in matrix:
    for col in row:
        print(col, end=" ")
    print()
```